# What is the actual name of these mysterious goddesses?

Tags: goddess, devi, tantra

In the Gondwana region of India, which stretches from Madhya Pradesh to Chhattisgarh, I read about few mysterious Goddesses in the tribal area. The tribes make use of the powers acquired by these goddesses in tantric rituals.

Few such names are: Goddess Marhi, Goddess Banjari etc.

I even searched these names in Devi Bhagwat and Durga Saptshati, but there are no such names. I asked few tribes and they say that Goddess Marhi is a form of Goddess Durga, but not Durga. She is one of the fierce form and has seven sisters. Goddess Banjari is one of them.

Has anyone heard the names before? If yes, please let me know what is the actual names of these Goddesses in Shastras.

Though all forms evolved from Goddess Parvathi, but still in Tantra world, these not considered one.

Comment: Any pics of these Goddesses?

Comment: No, but both these Goddesses are extensively worshiped for Shat Karmas in Tantra and considered fierce forms.

Comment: Ok, in which of the Shat Karmas can u say?

Comment: I met few tribal tantriks and they told me that they are used in Maran prayog.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you won't find such deities in authentic books because they are tribal deities.
Many tribal cultures have animal sacrifice customs too. Chhattisgarh is a very ancient tribal area dating back to as long as 5000 years ago.
They worship many local graama/sthaana devatas too which is not mentioned in traditional books.
Even in Orissa, there is quite a bit of tribal culture. There is a [yogini temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chausathi_Jogini_Temple) in Orissa which is worshiped by the tribes (64 yoginis).

As per the legend even [Lord Jagannatha](http://magazines.odisha.gov.in/Orissareview/june_july-2007/engpdf/Pages80-84.pdf) was once upon a time worshiped by the tribes of Chhattishgarh and later it arrived in Orissa and then slowly made into official temple worship.

Fire is a main part of most of tribal rituals.

Further reading [here](http://www.indianetzone.com/37/religious_life_indian_tribes.htm) and [here](http://www.sanctuaryasia.com/people/opinions/4367-acknowledging-the-importance-of-nature-and-tribal-cultural-and-religious-traditions.html).

Comment: One 64 Yoginis temple is near Jabalpur MP also. I have visited that. I am curious to know when these tribal deities are not in any scriptures, how they are able to perform those negative rituals.

Comment: @RKh yes there is temple in MP. Well every sects develop their own set of rituals. its a collective belief carried out since ages